# is it possible to use TypeScript and Babel together

Tags: javascript, typescript, babeljs

I am new to both TypeScript and Babel. I have researched both and found they have features the other does not have. I'd like get the best of both world by using TypeScript to organize my code then use babels ES6 features like asyc/await and others. Is this possible.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> I'd like get the best of both world by using TypeScript to organize my code then use babels ES6 features like asyc/await and others. Is this possible.

Not out of the box. I would recommend against it unless you are willing to start compiler hacking yourself. Reason is that since TypeScript doesn't understand async await yet you need to put babel *before* TypeScript and then the output generated by Babel will not be ideal *TypeScript* compilation target.

That said TypeScript should get async/await soon (3 / 4 months)

## Update

You can now use TypeScript `async/await` with `--target es6` and then use babel as a secondary transpiler.

In fact atom-typescript supports `typescript -> babel -> js` out of the box : https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/faq.md#can-i-use-an-alternate-transpiler

Comment: Thanks for the head up. I'll go ahead and go with TypeScript.

Comment: @Luke101 currently if you are willing to try out nightly release of TypeScript 1.6, you may use it to compile your source code to ES6 and then Babel to ES5. I tested some simple demo with TypeScript compiler and System.js (with Babel as transpiler), and it seemed to work.

Comment: With the release of typescript 1.7, async/await are enabled OOTB so pipelining babel should be even easier :)