# It is possible to transpile into TypeScript using Babel?

Tags: javascript, typescript, babeljs

I understand that Babel [now has support for TypeScript](https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-preset-typescript) style type-annotations. However, it does not check the types like the TypeScript compiler does, and it removes the type annotations from the output. What I would like to achieve is:

1. Transpile stage-0 code with TypeScript annotations to vanilla TypeScript
2. Check the types using the TypeScript compiler
3. Output JavaScript compatible with Node or the browser

Is this possible?

Comment: `@babel/preset-typescript` should allow you to use babel to transpile typescript instead of using `tsc`. Are you encountering issues with this?

Comment: @apokryfos - As the OP said, that just allows parsing the annotations, not type checking. See #2 on the OP's list above.

Comment: Then as far as I know this is not possible.

Comment: @apokryfos - Turns out it is! I was surprised, too, but now I feel guilty for being surprised... The Babel folks are really good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was curious so I [pinged Nicolò Ribaudo](https://twitter.com/tjcrowder/status/1191664832413675520) who does a lot of work on Babel, and it turns out this is easier than I thought: You can tell Babel to *parse* type annotations but not *remove* them by using the TypeScript *syntax plugin* (`@babel/plugin-syntax-typescript`) but not the TypeScript *preset* (`@babel/preset-typescript`).

For instance, if you wanted to transpile support for the pipeline operator, your `.babelrc` might look like this:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-typescript",
    [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-pipeline-operator",
      {
        "proposal": "minimal"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Then if you feed Babel this `.ts` file:

```
function doubleSay(str: string) {
  return str + ", " + str;
}
function capitalize(str: string) {
  return str[0].toUpperCase() + str.substring(1);
}
function exclaim(str: string) {
  return str + '!';
}

let result = "hello"
  |> doubleSay
  |> capitalize
  |> exclaim;

console.log(result);
```

...it generates this output with the pipeline operator transpiled but the type annotations still in place:

```
var _ref, _ref2, _hello;

function doubleSay(str: string) {
  return str + ", " + str;
}

function capitalize(str: string) {
  return str[0].toUpperCase() + str.substring(1);
}

function exclaim(str: string) {
  return str + '!';
}

let result = (_ref = (_ref2 = (_hello = "hello", doubleSay(_hello)), capitalize(_ref2)), exclaim(_ref));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: It doesn transpile them but the output files are still .js for me. Is there any way to preserve the given extensions (ts/tsx?)

EDIT: `babel src -d dist --extensions '.ts,.tsx' --keep-file-extension"` works

Comment: I love this answer as a way to use TC39 proposals with typescript in general. But the tsc error would be more difficult to read because the line numbers won't match. I wonder if there are any workaround for that.

Comment: @martian17 - I don't think so. In the configuration settings for the TypeScript compiler, it only talks about *producing* source maps, not *consuming* them. :-) Still, if you look at the error in the intermediate file, it shouldn't be too hard to then find it in the original.

Comment: On a related topic, how do I use Babel for transpiling, tsc for types ? I search SO and I can't useful Q&A for it, except for this and an old question asked in 2015 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30801857/is-it-possible-to-use-typescript-and-babel-together . I feel we should have a good answer for that in 2024 (almost).